# jgitflow:release-finish is not deleting the release branch

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, jgit, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I recently finished merging a release branch to master and develop using `jgitflow:release-finish`. The build was successful.

[image]

But now I am trying to create a new branch using `jgitflow:releast-start`. But it is giving the below error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start (default-cli) on project <XXXXXXX>: Error starting release: Error starting release: a release branch [refs/remotes/origin/release/1.0.1] already exists. Finish that first! -> [Help 1]
```

It asked me the below question when I ran `jgitflow:release-start` and I entered it as 1.0.2.

```
What is the release version for "XXXXXXX"? (org.XXX.automation:XXXXXXX) [1.0.2]: 1.0.2
```

But still it is giving the below error. I am puzzled.

**Questions**:

- Should we delete the release-1.0.1 branch manually?
- If yes, I will losing the history. Is there any way to preserve that?

Comment: I can confirm that it is working by deleting all branches (remotely too). I've heard said that having the release branches temporary is part of the Git philosophy so, maybe it's not that bad to delete them (also merged code is not lost).

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Should we delete the release-1.0.1 branch manually? 2) If yes, I will losing the history. Is there any way to preserve that?

According to [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#finishing-a-release-branch), the philosophy behind this Maven plugin, release branches are meant to be temporary branches which should be deleted afterwards:

> Now we are really done and the release branch may be removed, since we don’t need it anymore:
>
> ```
> $ git branch -d release-1.2
> Deleted branch release-1.2 (was ff452fe).
> ```

Changes for release preparation and complition are then merged, hence history of its changes is in most of the cases irrelevant.

However, a different approach is possible as a variant of gitflow (but obviously not directly supported by the plugin): keep a long living release branch, used for all releases and `rebase` it from the `develop` branch instead of creating a new one when ready to prepare/perform a release.

---

Also note that the [`release:finish`](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow/wiki/goals/release-finish) goal provides a [`keepbranch`](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow/wiki/goals/release-finish#!keepbranch) option:

> Whether to keep the release branch after finishing the release.

Default value to `false`, hence by default it should not keep the release branch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am not fiddling with `keepbranch` option. It should have deleted the release branch on local and remote.